# how to get the RecordType/Id name based on the ID

Tags: apex

I'm trying to find out the recordType Name/Id based on the record Id.

```
Id myid = 'a1aV0000003DzYE'; 
String sObjectType = ((Id)myid).getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();

//finding recordtype Name/Id ?
```

Comment: you need an sobject, not an sobjectType to find the recordTypeId - and it will be in field RecordTypeId

Comment: do you want to pass recordtype name or Id? Currently from your question you got object Name

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use following methods to get recordtype Name or Id based on the parameters passed to these methods.

```
public static Id getRecordTypeIdbyName(String objectName, String strRecordTypeName)
    {
        return  Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(strRecordTypeName).getRecordTypeId();
    }

    public static String getRecordTypeNameById(String objectName, Id strRecordTypeId)
    {
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById().get(strRecordTypeId).getName();
    }
```

**Update**

You need to query RecordTypeId through SOQL based on recordId.

```
SELECT Id, RecordtypeId, RecordType.name FROM Account where Id = '<your id>';
```

Comment: do you need to pass the recordtypename/id ? can we find out based on the record id which record type that particular record is using?

Comment: then you need to query for RecordTypeId based on recordId, no other way it can be found without query

Comment: There is a typo in getRecordTypeIdbyName, at the very end there is an extra bracket

Comment: @Mattisdada thanks for your comment, removed extra bracket.